# jQuery .fadeIn (and all jQuery) Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there's quite a few other threads about this, but none of them have worked for me.
I have a div that I'd like to fade in with jquery. (I originally wanted it to fade in when the user scrolled down, but that didn't work either, but if somebody could help me with that too, it would be great!)

Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
  $(".twitter-widget").fadeIn(5000);
});
</script>
<style>
  #twitter-widget {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 30px;
  }
</style>
<div style="text-align: center;" id="twitter-widget">
<div style="Background-color: white; Width: 200px; Height: 100px;" class="content">
<style>
  .rhett-link, .chadtronic, .here-now, .htde {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }`
</style>
<a href="https://twitter.com/averybmiller" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @averybmiller</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<br>
Followed By
<br>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/rhettandlink">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1617483791/RhettAndLink_Logo_RGB.jpg" height="40px" width="40px" alt="Rhett and Link" class="rhett-link"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/chadtronic">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/642137361124454400/p4Aui6FS.png" height="40px" width="40px" alt="Chadtronic" class="chadtronic"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/hereandnow">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000068124541/9fdeea271f46802d828b3b5a194df006.png" height="40px" width="40px" alt="NPR's Here and Now" class="here-now"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/htde">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/431891488675332096/DDbr4grY.png" height="40px" width="40px" alt="NPR's How to do Everything" class="htde"></a>
<br>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #FF5500; Width: 200px; Height: 2px"></div>
</div>
```

Now fadeIn., or anything jquery stuff for that matter, won't work. I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: `twitter-widget` must be hidden/no display `display:none;` for them to fade in. You can't fade something in if it's already visible. Also `$(".twitter-widget")` Is targeting elements with the class name of `twitter-widget` To target an `ID` use `#` not `.` Example: `$("#twitter-widget")`

Comment: Are your `<script>` tags stored in your `<head>`?

Answer (score 1):

`<style>` must be write inside head tag `<head></head>`,also your `<style>` tag has twice in html is not correct

your twitter-widget is id not class ,change `$(".twitter-widget").fadeIn(5000);` 
to `$("#twitter-widget").fadeIn(5000);`

```js
$("#twitter-widget").fadeOut(3000).fadeIn(3000);
```

```css
  #twitter-widget {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 30px;
      
  }
  .rhett-link, .chadtronic, .here-now, .htde {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align:center;" id="twitter-widget">
<div style="Background-color: white; Width: 200px; Height: 100px;" class="content">
<a href="https://twitter.com/averybmiller" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @averybmiller</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<br>
Followed By
<br>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/rhettandlink">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1617483791/RhettAndLink_Logo_RGB.jpg" height="40px" width="40px" alt="Rhett and Link" class="rhett-link"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/chadtronic">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/642137361124454400/p4Aui6FS.png" height="40px" width="40px" alt="Chadtronic" class="chadtronic"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/hereandnow">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000068124541/9fdeea271f46802d828b3b5a194df006.png" height="40px" width="40px" alt="NPR's Here and Now" class="here-now"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/htde">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/431891488675332096/DDbr4grY.png" height="40px" width="40px" alt="NPR's How to do Everything" class="htde"></a>
<br>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #FF5500; Width: 200px; Height: 2px"></div>
</div>
```